# PHP fetch files in directory in chronological order

Tags: php, file, list

I have a directory with files like 1245.jpg 123456.jpg 23435.jpg 99.jpg etc.

If I just use a opendir() , the files in the array are in alphabetically sorted order, but I want the files to be sorted in the order of the numbers their names are based on.

i.e an alphabetical order for the above set is
123456
1245
2345
99

Whereas a number sort would give
99
1245
2345
123456

Is there an easy way to do this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would be to read the whole file-name list into an array and sort it directly in php, and only then process the files.

```
$directory = "/path/to/the/directory";
$filenames = array();
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        $filenames[] = (int)$fileinfo->getBasename('.jpg');
    }
}
sort($filenames);
print_r($filenames);
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the files are in an array its easy using [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

```
foreach (glob("folder/*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $files[] = $filename;
}

sort($files, SORT_NUMERIC);

print_r($files);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just read all the file names in the directory into an array - then sort the array as you desire?